# RxJava flatMap does not interleave results

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

According to the ReactiveX documentation:

[image]

> Note that FlatMap merges the emissions of these Observables, so that
>   they may interleave.

I tried it out and seem to be hitting an issue.

Notice that the `11, 12, 13 and 14` all ran together on the `Scheduler.compute()` threads. Then `15 and 21` ran together 2 seconds later (expectedly, because of the specified delay in the `delayedIdentity(...)` function). However all succeeding runs happen 2 seconds after the preceding run (see line 7-10; data `22, 23, 24 and 25`). I expected these last 4 to interleave because I used `flatMap(...)`. It seems when using flatMap, it waits for the result of an element before proceeding to the next one which stops it from interleaving.

I also used a `delayedEcho(...)` alternative to `delayedIdentity(...)` which also produced a non interleaving result.

Given the following code:

```
public class Main {

    private static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0} {1} {2}", getLine(), Instant.now(), "Start"));

        Arrays.asList(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
                .stream()
                .map(n -> Observable.just(n))
                .map(o -> o
                        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                        .flatMap(Main::delayedIdentity)
                        .subscribe(Main::println))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        Observable.just(21, 22, 23, 24, 25)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .flatMap(Main::delayedIdentity)
                .subscribe(Main::println);

        Thread.sleep(25 * 1000);
    }

    public static Observable<Integer> delayedIdentity(Integer n) {
        return Observable.create(s -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
                s.onNext(n);
                s.onCompleted();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                s.onError(e);
            }
        });
    }

    public synchronized static void println(Object o) {
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0} {1} {2}", getLine(), Instant.now(), o));
    }

    public synchronized static int getLine() {
        return i++;
    }
}
```

Given the following console logs:

```
0 2016-07-21T06:05:36.908Z Start
1 2016-07-21T06:05:39.169Z 11
2 2016-07-21T06:05:39.169Z 14
3 2016-07-21T06:05:39.169Z 12
4 2016-07-21T06:05:39.170Z 13
5 2016-07-21T06:05:41.171Z 15
6 2016-07-21T06:05:41.172Z 21
7 2016-07-21T06:05:43.175Z 22
8 2016-07-21T06:05:45.176Z 23
9 2016-07-21T06:05:47.180Z 24
10 2016-07-21T06:05:49.182Z 25

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Echo alternative:

```
public static Observable<Integer> delayedEcho(Integer n) {
    return Observable.create(s -> {
        try {
            s.onNext(n);
            Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
            s.onNext(n);
            s.onCompleted();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            s.onError(e);
        }
    });
}
```

This resulted to the following similar results:

```
0 2016-07-21T06:13:19.867Z Start
1 2016-07-21T06:13:20.073Z 11
2 2016-07-21T06:13:20.074Z 14
3 2016-07-21T06:13:20.074Z 13
4 2016-07-21T06:13:20.075Z 12
5 2016-07-21T06:13:22.078Z 11
6 2016-07-21T06:13:22.079Z 12
7 2016-07-21T06:13:22.079Z 13
8 2016-07-21T06:13:22.080Z 14
9 2016-07-21T06:13:22.081Z 15
10 2016-07-21T06:13:22.081Z 21
11 2016-07-21T06:13:24.087Z 15
12 2016-07-21T06:13:24.087Z 21
13 2016-07-21T06:13:24.087Z 22
14 2016-07-21T06:13:26.089Z 22
15 2016-07-21T06:13:26.089Z 23
16 2016-07-21T06:13:28.091Z 23
17 2016-07-21T06:13:28.092Z 24
18 2016-07-21T06:13:30.094Z 24
19 2016-07-21T06:13:30.095Z 25
20 2016-07-21T06:13:32.098Z 25

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be sure that you understand `Schedulers.computation()` scheduler - it's not 1 thread, it's mostly like pool of threads. If 1 thread busy, it will return you new thread. To check it, just place something like

```
 System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Thread id = {0}", Thread.currentThread().getId()));
```

Inside your `delayedIdentity` function. Probably it will be more clear with that knowledge.

Im not 100% sure what is so confusing here for you, but I'll try to explain result step by step.

```
Arrays.asList(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
        .stream() 
        .map(n -> Observable.just(n)) 
        .map(o -> o 
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation()) 
                .flatMap(Main::delayedIdentity) 
                .subscribe(Main::println)) 
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

So when you run that code, all data from stream goes converted to `5 Observables`, which then, almost at them same time starts to emit only one item after delay `delayedIdentity`. And as result you'll see `11, 12, 13, 14, 15` in console almost at same time. It shouldn't save an order, because `stream` can pass in unordered state.

So, because you use non main thread in first statement, second statement will start right after first

```
   Observable.just(21, 22, 23, 24, 25) 
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation()) 
            .flatMap(Main::delayedIdentity) 
            .subscribe(Main::println);
```

So simply saying 21, will wait 2 seconds in `delayedIdentity` almost at same time as  `11, 12, 13, 14, 15`, and after that time all that number will be printed in console.  `22, 23, 24, 25` - will be printed each other after with period 2 seconds one by one.

Please ask me if it's not clear.

Comment: Since flatMap will execute them in a ``compute(...)`` thread, I expect the next in the observable to be executed immediately afterwards. This in effect should make them start the delay almost at the same time and interleave their results similar to the Stream code. Notice the results when using ``delayedEcho(...)``, ``22, 23, 24 and 25`` were all emitted twice after the other, and these results didn't interleave at all. This is unlike the example picture in the ``flatMap`` documentation in http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html which shows the green interleaving with the blue

Comment: `.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())` applied to `Observable`, not to each item! That's why second statement will be executed in `1 thread`. In first case you create 5 observables, and each of them will be executed at 1 thread.

Comment: Adding ``.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())`` seems to have fixed the issue. Can you edit your answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: @Chad Which one issue? It was working as expected. Please check that article for better understanding - http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.ru/2016/02/rxjava-understanding-observeon-and.html

Comment: I mean, you were correct. I needed to shift each observable into a new thread (using subscribeOn) instead of the one observable that contains them (currently using observeOn).

Comment: @Chad ok, great. Then close that question marking that answer as a right one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. :)